# Batch file to create folder if another already exists

Tags: batch-file

trying to create folder2 if folder1 exists in the parent location.. cant seem to get it to work. Tried with powershell, but it wont run from the server for some reason, so im trying to complete with a batch.

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') 
(
if exists "%%s\Folder1" do md "%%s\Folder2"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') DO (
 if exist "%%s\Folder1" md "%%s\Folder2"
)
```

Note: Missing `DO`; Open-parenthesis must be on same physical line as `DO`; `EXIST`, not `EXISTS`. `DO` erroneously included in `IF` statement

---------- Note amended text above! ^^^^^^^^

Demo batch:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

PUSHD U:\sourcedir

ECHO ======before...VVV
DIR /ad U:\sourcedir\err12

:: Ensure folder1 is missing...
RD err12\Folder1 2>nul
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') DO (
 if exist "%%s\Folder1" md "%%s\Folder2"
)

ECHO ======after...VVV (no folder1 so folder2 NOT created)
DIR /ad U:\sourcedir\err12

:: Make folder1
MD err12\Folder1 2>nul
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') DO (
 if exist "%%s\Folder1" md "%%s\Folder2"
)

ECHO ======after...VVV (folder1 so folder2 IS created)
DIR /ad U:\sourcedir\err12

:: Remove both folder1 and folder2
RD err12\Folder1 2>nul
RD err12\Folder2 2>nul
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') DO (
 if exist "%%s\Folder1" ECHO(md "%%s\Folder2"
)
ECHO ======after...VVV (no folder1 so folder2 NOT created AGAIN)
DIR /ad U:\sourcedir\err12


popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Note: I used `U:\sourcedir` for testing. `U:\sourcedir\err12` already exists.

Result (with a little whitepace inserted)

```
======before...VVV
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\err12

22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          .
22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,126,249,984 bytes free


======after...VVV (no folder1 so folder2 NOT created)
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\err12

22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          .
22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,126,249,984 bytes free


======after...VVV (folder1 so folder2 IS created)
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\err12

22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          .
22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          ..
22/07/2014  11:33    <DIR>          Folder1
22/07/2014  11:33    <DIR>          Folder2
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)   2,126,184,448 bytes free


======after...VVV (no folder1 so folder2 NOT created AGAIN)
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\err12

22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          .
22/07/2014  10:11    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,126,249,984 bytes free
```

So - works for me - after the `do` in the `if` statement was removed, but that would yield a `do is not recognised ...` error, not `%%s` as you've reported.

Comment: thanks, but now im getting an error: %%s not expected at this time...?